# Three models in to one maintenance form

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I want to build the one maintenance form for the following three models -

```
namespace mysite.Models
{
public class LevelOne
{
    public int LevelOneId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LevelTwo> LevelTwos { get; set; }
}

}
namespace mysite.Models
{
public class LevelTwo
{
    public int LevelTwoId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int LevelOneId { get; set; }
    public virtual LevelOne LevelOne { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LevelThree> LevelThrees { get; set; }
}
}

namespace mysite.Models
{
public class LevelThree
{
    public int LevelThreeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int LevelTwoId { get; set; }
    public virtual LevelTwo LevelTwo { get; set; }
}
}
```

The relationship is :- 
LevelOne can have multiple LevelTwo's.
LevelTwo's will have a LevelOne and multiple LevelThree's.
LevelThree will have a LevelTwo.

I have cascading ddl's to select based on the relationship above.
What would be the best way to implement a maintenance form so i can add/edit/delete a level based on what is chosen in the ddl's?
Is it a case of a lot of divs being hidden and shown in javascript based on the ddl's or can something simpler be done using viewmodels or some fancy nancy .net extensions etc?

My mind hurts thinking about it :(

Answer (score 0):

> This could also be seen as just 1 model with 3 entities.
>
> Level1 -> Level2 is a one to many relationship. Level2 -> Level3 is a
>   one to many relationship.
>
> EF supports this. And as i clearly see from ur namespace for all
>   the 3 models is the same mysite.Models, i guess u already have all of
>   them in the same model file for EF to create the relationships.